# Naturally type decimal values with QDoubleSpinBox

Tags: c++, qt

QDoubleSpinBox functionality is required to provide the user with the option to simply click the arrow keys and easily increase the value by certain points. But it is absolutely necessary that the user is able to enter the decimal value manually as well. 
Eg. If he needs to type 12.25 by typing, he should be able to. But if he needs to increase it by 0.01 he still should be able to use the arrows in the spinbox and do it as well.

Under normal configurations he can not enter 12.25 at one go. if he types 12 and then the decimal point, it does not move to the decimal section of the spin box, or even after that you have to select 0.1 and type the 0.1 section and then move to 0.01 using arrow keys and type the 0.01 part of the dobule value.

Is there any property that will help me get the expected behaviour of typing 12.15 in one go, without selecting each and every digit.

Comment: You can define the single step that the arrows increase / decrease.

setSingleStep(double step), see  
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html#singleStep-prop

In your case you could do setSingleStep(0.1). 

For the behavior you asked, I did not find a way to do it. Many people say to reimplement QDoubleSpinBox.

Comment: Did you ever find a good way to just type in values?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the locale (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#setLocale) you might have to take a look at the decimal separator your control is expecting (e.g. ',' or '.').

You can either set the locale as you prefer or override this behavior by subclassing the control in the [keyPressEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent)